# TypeError: variables_initializer() missing 1 required positional argument: 'var_list'

Tags: tensorflow

**CODE**

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

x_train = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
y_train = [-1.0, -2.0, -3.0, -4.0]

W = tf.Variable(initial_value=[1.0], dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable(initial_value=[1.0], dtype=tf.float32)

x = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32)
y_input = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32)

y_output = W * x + b

loss = tf.reduce_sum(input_tensor=tf.square(x=y_output - y_input))
optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
train_step = optimizer.minimize(loss=loss)

session = tf.compat.v1.Session()
session.run(tf.compat.v1.variables_initializer())

print(session.run(fetches=loss, feed_dict={x: x_train, y_input: y_train}))

for _ in range(1000):
    session.run(fetches=train_step, feed_dict={x: x_train, y_input: y_train})

print(session.run(fetches=[loss, W, b], feed_dict={x: x_train, y_input: y_train}))

print(session.run(fetches=y_output, feed_dict={x: [5.0, 10.0, 15.0]}))
```

**ERROR**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/phycarm projects/linearRegression.py", line 20, in <module>
session.run(tf.compat.v1.variables_initializer())
  TypeError: variables_initializer() missing 1 required positional argument: 'var_list'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

**OK just add var_list in variable initailizer as below**

you just need to type yor variable you defined in the var list

session.run(tf.compat.v1.variables_initializer(var_list=[W, b]))

**Here is the right code:-**

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

x_train = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
y_train = [-1.0, -2.0, -3.0, -4.0]

W = tf.Variable(initial_value=[1.0], dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable(initial_value=[1.0], dtype=tf.float32)

x = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32)
y_input = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32)

y_output = W * x + b

loss = tf.reduce_sum(input_tensor=tf.square(x=y_output - y_input))
optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
train_step = optimizer.minimize(loss=loss)

session = tf.compat.v1.Session()
session.run(tf.compat.v1.variables_initializer(var_list=[W, b]))

print(session.run(fetches=loss, feed_dict={x: x_train, y_input: y_train}))

for _ in range(1000):
    session.run(fetches=train_step, feed_dict={x: x_train, y_input: y_train})

print(session.run(fetches=[loss, W, b], feed_dict={x: x_train, y_input: y_train}))

print(session.run(fetches=y_output, feed_dict={x: [5.0, 10.0, 15.0]}))
```